# Ler um txt evitando problemas com acentos em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando ler um arquivo txt porém utilizando a função abaixo para exibir cores no terminal e sempre que o arquivo possui acentos ele me retorna tudo bagunçado.

```py
COLORS = {\
"black":"\u001b[30;1m",
"negrito":"\u001b[1m",
"reset":"\u001b[0m",
"red": "\u001b[31;1m",
"green":"\u001b[32m",
"yellow":"\u001b[33;1m",
"blue":"\u001b[34;1m",
"magenta":"\u001b[35m",
"cyan": "\u001b[36m",
"white":"\u001b[37m",
"brown":"\u001b[94m",
"yellow-background":"\u001b[43m",
"black-background":"\u001b[40m",
"cyan-background":"\u001b[46;1m",
}

def colorText(text):
    for color in COLORS:
        text = text.replace("[[" + color + "]]", COLORS[color])
    return text

def lertxt() :
    f = open("olamundo.txt", "r")
    arquivo = "".join(f.readlines())
    print(colorText(arquivo))
    f.close()
    return

lertxt()
```

com o conteúdo do txt sendo

> "Olá mundo"

ele me retorna

> "olÃ¡ mundo"

Pesquisei e acredito ser um problema de codificação mas não sei onde e 
como forçar a codificação correta, como resolver?

Comment: É no próprio `open`, algo assim: `open('olamundo.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')` - obviamente, trocando o encoding para aquele no qual o arquivo está

Comment: coloquei e ficou assim: `f = open("olamundo.txt", encoding="utf-8", mode="r")` porém continua não funcionando, acho que por mais que ele use o open com o encoding utf-8 a mudança do encode está ocorrendo na hora que é chamada a função colorText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui descobrir a solução funcional e no caso seria importar o IO e editar a linha do comando open ficando da seguinte maneira:

```py
import io

f= io.open("olamundo.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
```

Para quem quiser compreender melhor o módulo **io** pode ler mais sobre em
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar a variável do texto para algo do tipo:

```
string = u'N\ze3o'.encode('utf-8')
```

Ou então, você já tentou usar `.decode('latin_1')` ?

Funcionou comigo!

Comment: então mas no meu caso o problema é onde inserir o comando para ele forçar a codificação correta, já que eu não posso inserir na função do print (lertxt) pois ela irá retornar à função do replace (colorText) não só um valor em string mas também um valor em bytes e isso resumirá em um erro

Answer (score -2):

```
arq_entrada=open('estatuto.txt',encoding='latin-1',mode='r')
print(arq_entrada.read())
```

Answer (score -3):

Aqui tive problema com a leitura dos dados através de um arquivo ini e que foi resolvido usando

```
cfg.read('CONFIG-TS.ini', encoding='utf-8')
```